# Algebra manipulation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am rusty in algebra. I am doing a proof by induction and I don't know how the first statement is equal to the second one.

$(k+1)!$ + $(k+1)(k+1)! - 1$ = $ (1+(k+1))(k+1)!-1$

How we got from $(k+1)! + (k+1)$ to $(1+(k+1))$ ?

Comment: Are you sure you typed it out exactly? Sure the second term on LHS is not supposed to be $(k+1)(k+1)!$ [note the factorial]?

Comment: @Deepak I am sorry. I corrected it.

Comment: What happens if   we take $(k+1)!$ out as common factor

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $a + ba - 1 = a(1+b)-1$. Taking $a:= (k+1)!$ and $b:= (k+1)$ shows the result.

In fact, we have $n! = n(n-1) \cdots 1 = n(n-1)!$ for all $n \geq 1$.

Comment: I got it but I got stuck in a step after it. How come $(k+2)(k+1)!$ get to $(k+2)!$ ?

Comment: @Altaïr That's because $(k+1)! = (k+1)\cdot (k) \cdot (k-1) \cdot ... 1$ and $(k+2)! = (k+2)\cdot (k+1) \cdot (k) ... 1$ Do you see?